# Error "The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int"

Tags: java, eclipse

> Mi código va bien hasta que en  --->   if (nota[i] > 12) {
> System.out.println("Ingrese un numero valido");
> return;
> Me da ese error -> Error "The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int"

import java.util.Scanner;
public class aa {

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje menciona que no se puede comparar String e int, deberias convertir la cadena a entero, justamente abajo estas haciendo algo similar

```
if (Integer.parseInt(nota[i]) >= 7) {
            System.out.println("Alumno: " + nombres[i] + " Nota: " + nota[i]);
        }
```

al no poder comparar la cadena con un numero, manda ese mensaje de error, pero si conviertes la cadena a un entero se arreglara tu problema

```
Integer.parseInt(nota[i])
```

Comment: Perfecto, es verdad abajo hice lo mismo.